# Set cross section of pandas MultiIndex to DataFrame from addition of other cross sections

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, multi-index

I am currently trying to assign rows with certain indices based on the other indices within the group.

Consider the following pandas data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('abc'), ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.arange(9), 
                   'col2': np.arange(9, 18), 
                   'col3': np.arange(18,27)}, 
                   index=index)
```

Output of `df`:

```
      col1  col2  col3
a aa     0     9    18
  bb     1    10    19
  cc     2    11    20
b aa     3    12    21
  bb     4    13    22
  cc     5    14    23
c aa     6    15    24
  bb     7    16    25
  cc     8    17    26
```

I want to assign the indices 'cc' equal to 'aa' plus 'bb' per the first level of indices.

The following works fine, but I am wondering if there is a way to set values without having to reference the underlying NumPy array.

```py
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'cc'], :] = (df.xs('aa', level=1) 
                                     + df.xs('bb', level=1)).values
```

Is there a way to set the 'cc' rows directly to the output below? I believe the issue with trying to set the below directly is due to an index mismatch. Can I get around this somehow?

```py
df.xs('aa', level=1) + df.xs('bb', level=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```
df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values(1)=='cc'] = df.xs('aa', level=1) + df.xs('bb', level=1)
```

---

**Old answer**

You can do this:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(1)=='cc'] = df.xs('aa', level=1) + df.xs('bb', level=1)
```

Disclaimer: it works for pandas version 1.2.1 and it doesn't work in pandas 1.2.3. I haven't tested any other version

Comment: Hi @Pablo C, that was not my downvote. Does this run into any issues with setting a copy?

Comment: @JackMoody hi :) what do you mean? I don't fully understand your question

Comment: Nevermind. If I do run into `SettingWithCopyWarning`, I should just be able to use `loc` in this situation.

Comment: Not my downvote.  But seen your code produces `nan` values on all `cc` rows.

Comment: @SeaBean that's weird. Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: @Pablo C I tried this code and it doesn't seem to work. I think the issue is as mentioned in the original question - indexing not matching up.

Comment: @JackMoody Which pandas version are you using? it works perfectly in my computer

Comment: I use version 1.2.3.  Have to modify it to use .`values` like the question to get it right.

Comment: @SeaBean it works in v1.2.1 but doesn't work in v1.2.3, I already tested it...

Comment: @JackMoody check it now

Comment: That fixes it. Thanks! Weird that it would break like that in a patch.

Comment: @JackMoody I'm happy to help! :D